# IService<T> or defining IProductService, ICustomerService

Tags: c#, interface

As per tutorial [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-awesome-guide-on-how-to-build-restful-apis-with-asp-net-core-87b818123e28/), I have the following classes:

(In reference to this tutorial's section)

```
namespace Supermarket.API.Domain.Services
{
    public interface ICategoryService
    {
         Task<IEnumerable<Category>> ListAsync();
    }
}
```

**IProductService.cs**

```
namespace Supermarket.API.Domain.Services
{
    public interface IProductService
    {
         Task<IEnumerable<Product>> ListAsync();
    }
}
```

**ICustomerService.cs**

```
namespace Supermarket.API.Domain.Services
{
    public interface ICustomerService
    {
         Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> ListAsync();
    }
}
```

I have about 10 Domains that I want to have the same interface as above (i.e. the service ability to `GET` items for e.g. Customer / Product / OrderItem / Order)

In view of the DRY principle, I am thinking of changing to the below:

```
public interface IService<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a collection of entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync();
}
```

Whereby at implementation time, it looks like the below:

```
public class CustomerService : IService<Customer>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> ListAsync()
    {
        var entities =  await // Imeplementation of DAL to follow

        return entities;
    }
}
```

None of the tutorials that I have read so far does anything similar to keep the interface DRY. Is this a good idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It makes perfect sense to define such generic interface as long as there is a generic consumer that can do some useful work with any of the implementations.

And I suppose there is in this case.

If I were to guess, I'd say the tutorial did not include generics just because that is a feature that might not be familiar to the audience that the tutorial was pointing at.

As @Hayden already mentioned, `IService<T>` is not a very useful name. Let me call it `IEntityListProvider<T>` instead.

I can imagine the common consumer could be a single route controller.

Let me first a define a simple routing framework to provide some context:

```
// IRequest and IResponse are models of HTTP request resp. response
interface IRequestHandler
{
  public Task<IResponse> HandleAsync(IRequest request);
}

interface IRouterBuilder
{
  // register a GET route handler
  public void Get(string path, IRequestHandler handler);

  // build the router instance
  public IRequestHandler Build();
}
```

now we can implement the generic consumer like this:

```
class EntityListRouteHandler<T> : IRequestHandler
{
  private IEntityListProvider<T> Provider;

  // add constructor to take the dependency

  Task<IResponse> HandleAsync(IRequest request)
  {
    // get the list from provider
    // and convert the list to a response in a way
    // that's going to be the same for all entities
  }
}
```

and somewhere in router factory you would do somethig like this:

```
RouterBuilder.Get('/categories', new EntityListRouteHandler<Category>(categoriesProvider));
RouterBuilder.Get('/products', new EntityListRouteHandler<Product>(productProvider));
RouterBuilder.Get('/customers', new EntityListRouteHandler<Customer>(customersProvider));
```

Now I would like to expand on @Hayden's answer.

Ad 1) he mentions that if a `PasswordService` were to exist, it would probably not need a `ListAsync` method. Well, that's true, but it's misleading because it is irrelevant. Such a service would simply not implement the `IEntityListProvider<T>` interface.

Ad 2) if some service needs some more methods, then I would ask mayself is there someone who needs those methods at the same time? If yes just create a new interface extending the base one. If not, just define a new separate interface. Whether the concrete class implements two interfaces or you simply provide two different classes to implement each of the two interfaces is up to you. But a separate class for each interface feels like it better follows SRP.

I would add one more note regarding pagination. It is not very wise to provide the lists of entities without any limit. The momory consumption of such program is then out of control unless there is some logic that prevents too many entities to exist in the first place. Your `ListAsync` method should have arguments for pagination and possibly filtering and sorting as those are very common things to do with list resources. The type of these arguments may as well be generic arguments of the interface. I.e. `Task<IEnumerable<T>> IEntityListProvider<T, F, S, P>::ListAsync(F filter, S sort, P page)` or so...

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, but...

In the current picture you painted, where all the services are structurally *exactly* the same, you can indeed use the generic base interface. Your code will work exactly as you expect it to.

However, in reality what starts off as an similar structure often ends up diverging, e.g. `CustomerService.GetUnderageCustomers()` making no sense to be implemented on the other services.

### ...it's better to have the best of both worlds.

Keep your generic interface:

```
public interface IService<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync();
}
```

But also define your specific interface types, relying on that generic interface where relevant:

```
public interface IProductService : IService<Product> { }

public interface ICategoryService : IService<Category> { }

public interface ICustomerService : IService<Customer> 
{ 
     Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetUnderageCustomersAsync();
}
```

Notice how I was able to extend the contract of the customer service, without needing to suddenly create an `ICustomerService` where none would've existed before (i.e. when you only would have had the generic service interface).

If you had done it your way, if you then had to extend your customer service with `GetUnderageCustomersAsync`, you would've had to change your `CustomerService : IService<Customer>` to `CustomerService : ICustomerService`, which in turn would require you to re-evaluatle all references in your codebase to see if they need to move from using a `IService<Customer>` dependency to using a `ICustomerService` dependency.
That is a lot of work, there's a big change you're going to forget it here or there, and you're liable to introduce bugs or inconsistencies.

Creating the specific `I[xxx]Service` interfaces from the beginning allows your codebase to adapt to new features without introducing breaking changes, since you don't have to change the interface implementation hierarchy anymore.

- New method that applies to all those services? Add it to the generic base interface
- New method that applies to a specific service? Add it to the specific interface

### Is the generic interface necessary?

That's arguable. If there is some reusable logic that applies to all services, then having that generic base interface type makes a lot of sense, as it helps you to streamline your reusable service logic handling code, or even your test suite.

However, if you end up never really using the `IService<>` type directly in your code, then the interface doesn't really add any value, other than keeping your services structurally similarly, so they e.g. don't have varying `ListAsync`/`GetAllAsync`/`Get`/... methods that do the same thing but just end up being named differently.

In short, there are two reasons to use this generic base interface

- When there is actually reusable code that can handle *any* `IService<T>`.
- When you want to enforce a clean and consistent interface across multiple types for reasons of human readability.

Comment: Why would adding a method to customer service require to change every class that was already using it as the generic service? Only those who need the new method have to change and that's presumably zero places in the existing code and one in code that you are yet to write.

Comment: @slepic: If you use a DI framework and the repository is not transient (which repositories usually aren't), you're going to want to stick with one interface type to request your non-transient dependency. You are, however, correct that not all references should be changes, and that's part of the issue: needing to evaluate each reference individually instead of a blanket find and replace. I didn't explain that part well, I'll improve it in the answer. But I disagree that it's "presumably zero places" as an additional feature is liable to change or further extend existing behavior as well.

Comment: @Flater In standard ASP.Net Core with EF Core there's rarely a reason to register the repository as anything but transient - the state is kept in the DbContext which is scoped.

Comment: @Voo: Those are a whole lot of ifs that the question does not specify.

Comment: @Flater It's the default and what's used in tutorials and samples by Microsoft. You're making the assumptions that someone puts state into the repository and then registers the class with the DI container twice (something so dubious that I've written explicit tests in the past to make sure nobody makes such a mistake).

Comment: @Voo: The comment I responded to explicitly suggests using _both_ `IService<Customer>` and `ICustomerService` dependency types in the codebase, which would always have to be registered separately, thus registering the concrete `ConsumerRepository` twice.

Comment: @Flater The usual solution that I'm aware of is to register the actual type (or one of the interfaces) and use a lambda to register the other interfaces by resolving them registered scoped type. Not pretty, but you can nicely hide that behind a helper method and certainly much better than having duplicate state.

Comment: @Flater If additional feature of interface X forces a change to class Y that depends on X, you're going to have to change the class Y anyway (to use the new method of X) even if you dont have to change the type of the dependency. The need to evaluate each reference individually exists regardless of the interface X being a generic interface or a specific service interface.

Comment: It's actually quite the opposite. If I added a method to existing interface X and there is a class Z that does not need this new method then I have to change this class Z to take the generic interface rather then the specifi service interface otherwise if I don't change the class Z, I am suddenly injecting a method to Z, but Z will never use this method which break ISP and I got myself to this state by changing a completly different piece of codebase and maybe even not knowing that Z exists.

Answer (score 3):

To get part of the code review out of the way, and possibly a copy paste error on your part, but the `I` prefix is reserved for interfaces, not classes. Therefore the last code snippet should be rewritten as:

```
public class CustomerService : IService<Customer>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> ListAsync()
    {
        var entities =  await // Imeplementation of DAL to follow

        return entities;
    }
}
```

To your question of whether it's a good idea to replace the interfaces with a generic interface in the name of DRY, it depends.

As a general guide into the DRY principle, you will need to identify whether the duplication in the code is truly a duplication, or whether the "duplication" is semantically different.

As an example, say that we have the following code:

```
public class Payslip
{
    public decimal Pay { get; set; }
    public decimal CalculateTaxAmount()
    {
        return Pay * 0.1M;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal CalculateTaxAmount()
    {
        return Price * 0.1M;
    }
}
```

This is obviously hyper simplified, but we can see that both classes have a `CalculateTaxAmount` method, which does essentially the same calculation to get the tax amount. If we were naive, and decided to refactor this to share the same logic, for example:

```
public abstract class BaseTaxable
{
    protected decimal _amount;

    public decimal CalculateTaxAmount()
    {
        return _amount * 0.1M;
    }
}

public class Payslip : BaseTaxable
{
    public decimal Pay { get => _amount; set => _amount = value; }
}

public class Item : BaseTaxable
{
    public decimal Price { get => _amount; set => _amount = value; }
}
```

We've removed the duplication from both `Item` and `Payroll`, but these two objects fundamentally calculate tax differently.

Say that the government decides to implement tax brackets for salaries, we would have to undo our refactoring on the `Payslip` object just to implement tax brackets.

Back to your use case, this does look fine to do, but you need to ask yourself:

1. Is the current contract for `IService<T>` represent what all services will be in your project? What if you decided to add a `PasswordService`? I don't think that having a `ListAsync` for passwords is a good idea.
2. What if, for example, `ICustomerService` requires additional functionality as part of it's contract? How do you expect to handle this use case? You can add additional interfaces onto your implementation but depending on your current code base, replacing references to accommodate this could be time consuming
3. As we discussed above, do the classes that implement this interface semantically perform the same functionality. In the case for retrieving domain entities, probably yes, but is something to keep in mind.

If you decide to refactor to use `IService<T>`, it's best to rename the interface to something more meaningful (i.e. `IReadOnlyRepository<T>`).

Comment: (1) is a very very strong reason that I can comprehend.

In my mind, it seems "overkill" to create an interface that is quite specific (e.g. `ICustomerService`), hence thinking of expanding to a general `Service` class.

Comment: * hence thinking of expanding to a general `IService<T>` class.

Answer (score 1):

@Flater, @slepic, and @Hayden answers have almost cover common case scenarios on when and where to use a generic (or generalized) interface to reuse it. As there are many real world cases applying the same concept. For instance, in .NET, `IEnumerable` interface is implemented in most .NET collections and arrays. All of which adds the ability to have one generic interface that implements many different collection types. The benefit here is to have a shared minimum requirement on all collection along with implementing a specific interface for each type (e.g. IList). when you see it up-close, you'll see how is it easy to extend, maintain, and also reuse and it how easy would be to convert between collection types (say from List to Array).

Another thing that you must consider in tutorials, almost all of them will have the long approach. This is because they're targeting a wide range of audience with different skills. So, every author tries to be as descriptive as possible to cover all audience. In which readers can understand and take the idea then improve it in their way. This is why you thought about `ISerivce` and `DRY` principle (improve it in your way). because you've got the idea and you can complete the work on your own.